# Is there any way to make nested array as main array in mongo aggregate pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This the response of aggregate pipeline:

```
[
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "_id":"63ee1b07c2c7d98d1e6b7e13",
            "username":"jhon_doe",
            "image":"https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/b39d30-0c50-4427-9fdb-2109880c7e09.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "_id":"63f34aed91981065e0edccc3",
            "username":"jane_doe",
            "image":"https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/9c56a5-b43c-40bd-946f-7091df1fb92b.jpeg"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is there any way to make the `data` named array elements as the main response array elements?

I need an output something like this:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"63ee1b07c2c7d98d1e6b7e13",
      "username":"jhon_doe",
      "image":"https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/b39d30-0c50-4427-9fdb-2109880c7e09.jpeg"
   },
   {
      "_id":"63f34aed91981065e0edccc3",
      "username":"jane_doe",
      "image":"https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/9c56a5-b43c-40bd-946f-7091df1fb92b.jpeg"
   }
]
```

Comment: Is this the output you want? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HZvDwQNqp2b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `data` array into multiple documents.
2. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with `data` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HZvDwQNqp2b)